# Symfony redirec to to login page after session expiration

Tags: session, authentication, authorization, symfony

I have implemented a restful api.
And I've got a problem with session handling.
When session timed out, user can refresh the page and then he gets 500 error because $this->getUser() is empty, and I need logged user data for this endpoint.
So instead of this I want to throw 403 error or just redirect to some url, when user refreshes the page and his session has expired.
How can I do it?
I guess I should use kernel listener, but how to check the session is already expired? Maybe there is a solution with only modifying security.yml?

I forgot to mention I use jms/di-extra-bundle, so I inject managers to controllers. These managers run before controller action, so I need to check if user is still logged in manager, not in controller. I don't want to duplicate code in every manager's actions, how can I do it in more elegant way?

I tried to use listener with kernel* action, for example:

```
class KernelListener
{

private $tokenStorage;

public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
{
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
}

public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    $kernel    = $event->getKernel();
    $request   = $event->getRequest();
            $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

    if(!$user instanceof SempUser || $user == null) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException();
    }
}

public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
{
    $response  = $event->getResponse();
    $request   = $event->getRequest();
    $kernel    = $event->getKernel();

    $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

    if(!$user instanceof SempUser || $user == null) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException();
    }

}

public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
{
    $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

    if(!$user instanceof SempUser || $user == null) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException();
    }

}

}
```

And my services.yml:

```
kernel.listener:
        class: AppBundle\Listener\KernelListener
        arguments: ["@security.token_storage"]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, method: onKernelResponse }
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Can you share some code with us ? Maybe this link will help you http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html

Comment: Hi there, I have included some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

For session handling I would suggest to take advantage of security.yml. You can define firewall rules and the secured areas for you application (http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/firewall_restriction.html).

You can then create a `YourOwnFactory` class that extends `Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\DependencyInjection\Security\Factory\AbstractFactory` and implements `Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\DependencyInjection\Security\Factory\SecurityFactoryInterface` in which you can define you own auth provider that will handle the authentication hence session handling.

Read more about it here http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_authentication_provider.html

**security.yml**

```
security:
    firewalls:
        [...]
        secured_area:
            pattern: ^/
            your_own_factory: ~ #tells symfony to use the AppBundle\Security\YourOwnFactory
```

Comment: Thank you, that's not what I want to do. This listener handles authentication failure/success, I want to handle session expiration.